# Complex XML Processing with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and got new task to using XML & XSLT.

I have xml file which ahs lot have child and thier sub child.

Now when i porcess xml using xsl it work fine for parent node but child node i am not getting any data.
 XML File :

```
<jrnl:bodytext>
        <level>
            <bodytext>
                <pgrp>
                    <heading>
                        <title>
                            <emph typestyle="bf">1. Orange</emph>
                        </title>
                    </heading>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 2<text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                    </p>



                </pgrp>
                <pgrp>
                    <heading>
                        <title>
                            <emph typestyle="bf">2. Apple </emph>
                        </title>
                    </heading>
                    <pgrp>
                        <heading>
                            <title>(a) Introduction</title>
                        </heading>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                        </p>
                    </pgrp>
                    <pgrp>
                        <heading>
                            <title>(b) The Facts</title>
                        </heading>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 2</text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                        </p>


                    </pgrp>
                    <pgrp>
                        <heading>
                            <title>(c) Mango</title>
                        </heading>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 2</fnr>
                            </text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                        </p>

                    </pgrp>
                    <pgrp>
                        <heading>
                            <title>(d) Misreading of Authority</title>
                        </heading>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 2</text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                        </p>

                    </pgrp>
                    <pgrp>
                        <heading>
                            <title>(e) The case</title>
                        </heading>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 2
                            </text>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                        </p>

                    </pgrp>
                </pgrp>
                <pgrp>
                    <heading>
                        <title>
                            <emph typestyle="bf">3. Principles</emph>
                        </title>
                    </heading>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 2</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 3</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 4</text>
                    </p>

                </pgrp>
                <pgrp>
                    <heading>
                        <title>
                            <emph typestyle="bf">4. Guidelines </emph>
                        </title>
                    </heading>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 2</text>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <l>
                            <li>
                                <lilabel>(i)</lilabel>
                                <p>
                                    <text>Paragraph 2.1</text>
                                </p>
                            </li>

                        </l>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <text>Pragraph 3</text>
                    </p>
                </pgrp>
                <pgrp>
                    <heading>
                        <title>
                            <emph typestyle="bf">5. Conclusion</emph>
                        </title>
                    </heading>
                    <p>
                        <text>Paragraph 1</text>
                    </p>
                </pgrp>
            </bodytext>


        </level>
    </jrnl:bodytext>
```

Now I want get all the , heading and text data. Though i can get all outer  data but i can't get their child  data.

Here is XSL code

```
<xsl:for-each select="//jrnl:bodytext/level/bodytext/pgrp">
      <xsl:text>$T$=</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="heading/title/emph"/>
          <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <xsl:text>$T</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
              <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

To extending this question , Now i have tried the same code as suggested but nothing happen.

Please see below, what i have tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:jrnl="http://www.abc.com/glp/jrnl" >

<xsl:template match="//jrnl:bodytext">
    <xsl:for-each select="level/bodytext">
        <xsl:for-each select="pgrp">
            <xsl:text>$T$=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="heading/title/emph"/>
            <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="p">
                <xsl:text>$T</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text> </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and what output i got is

```
$T$=1. Orange
    $TParagraph 1
    $TParagraph 2
    $TParagraph 3
$T$=2. Apple 
$T$=3. Principles
    $TParagraph 1
    $TParagraph 2
    $TParagraph 3
    $TParagraph 4
$T$=4. Guidelines 
    $TParagraph 1
    $TParagraph 2
    $T
    $TPragraph 3
$T$=5. Conclusion
    $TParagraph 1
```

I this case ,text entris for pgrp 2(Apple) must greater then one whereas in output  i got only 1 entry i.e. $T$=2. Apple

Comment: Please add the input value and the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following input fragment

```
<pgrp>
    <heading>
        <title>
            <emph typestyle="bf">2. Apple </emph>
        </title>
    </heading>
    <pgrp>
```

Here, we can see that there is a  within a . Hence the selector in

```
<xsl:for-each select="//jrnl:bodytext/level/bodytext/pgrp">
```

does not work. To make this work, you'll need to select the pgrp in a separate for-each tag under the current tag

Comment: Though i can do this but the problem is since the XMl file is dynamically generated so there might be many pgrp tag under each parent pgrp tag so in that case i need some recursive function which will automatically invoke each pgrp tag and process untill last pgrp tag. So in that how can i achive it as i have tried many other recursive function in this code but nothing work

Comment: Exactly, so select the pgrp without selecting parent <xsl:for-each select="//jrnl:bodytext/level/bodytext/pgrp"> should be <xsl:for-each select="//jrnl:bodytext/level/bodytext"> <xsl:for-each select = "pgrp">